# WebAPI Get Fails when resource id is structured with a hyphen (dash) -

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

This error just started occurring.  Everything was working, and then all the sudden this error started occurring when making a WebAPI Get call.

500.19 --> Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'aspNetCore'

In the WebAPI project, I can change the "App URL" in project properties, and this will create a new IIS Application, and with this application everything will now work just fine.  So, if I go and delete the original application in IIS.  Go back to Visual Studio, and re-enter the old App URL so that it re-created the App in IIS under the old name, and run it.  It fails again.  It's brand new.  Exact same code base regardless of which IIS Application is executing the code, but the original one never works anymore in the case described below - even after deleting it and recreating it.  It must be a crazy bug, because I did not modify anything.  It just automatically started to break in the middle of testing.

It only happens when the call I make has a dash character in the URI id.
Example: 
http://mysite/api/products/product10 works fine and the code executes.
But:
http://mysite/api/products/product10-1 does not work, the WebAPI is never hit, and the error is shown below.  I didn't make any changes to routing or web.config, nor to the Controller.  I don't understand what changed here.

WebAPI .NET Core 2.0 running on Windows / IIS.

Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'aspNetCore'

```
4:     <handlers>
5:       <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
6:     </handlers>
```

Signatures:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Product")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
```

Comment: What about root `Web.config` and `Machine.config`? Do either of those have an `aspNetCore` handler?

Comment: Yes.  The web.config has it.  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" /> . See my edit.  I've found that if I create a brand new App in IIS pointed to the same folder as before everything works.  If I delete the original app and re-create it, it still fails.  So, it's something at the IIS or system level.  Code is the same regardless of app.  It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for us was a Rewrite that we did for schema urls in Startup.cs file. Since Rewrite did that url modification on all urls, all request which include dashes got affected. We have removed the following line from Startup.cs and it worked as expected.

```
.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(@"(.*)/([a-z-]+)(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2})", "$1/$2$3.json", true))
```

This was written to get rid of .json extension in schema urls but affected all urls.
Check out your Startup.cs and look for something like this. You might have done a modification that affected all urls.